# Input email control indexOf method

Tags: javascript, forms

I have written this code but it doesn't work. I click the button check `input:email` and check the text.

```js
function EpostaKontrol(eposta) {
    if (eposta.indexof("@") != -1) {
        var dizi = eposta.split("@");
        if (!(alfaNummerikKonrol(dizi[0]))) {
            if (domain.indexof(".") != -1) {
                var domain = dizi[1].split(".");
                if (dizi[0].length >= 3 && dizi[1].length >= 5 && domain[1].length >= 2)
                    alert("Email Format Wrong");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: are you trying to validate if the string is a valid email address?

Comment: Yes i trying to validate email address

Comment: you can use `<input type="email">` and it will automatically validate it's an email address for you

Comment: I can't this way. I must write my checking code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please run the code snippet below:

```js
function validateEmail(email) {    
    return /^([^\x00-\x20\x22\x28\x29\x2c\x2e\x3a-\x3c\x3e\x40\x5b-\x5d\x7f-\xff]+|\x22([^\x0d\x22\x5c\x80-\xff]|\x5c[\x00-\x7f])*\x22)(\x2e([^\x00-\x20\x22\x28\x29\x2c\x2e\x3a-\x3c\x3e\x40\x5b-\x5d\x7f-\xff]+|\x22([^\x0d\x22\x5c\x80-\xff]|\x5c[\x00-\x7f])*\x22))*\x40([^\x00-\x20\x22\x28\x29\x2c\x2e\x3a-\x3c\x3e\x40\x5b-\x5d\x7f-\xff]+|\x5b([^\x0d\x5b-\x5d\x80-\xff]|\x5c[\x00-\x7f])*\x5d)(\x2e([^\x00-\x20\x22\x28\x29\x2c\x2e\x3a-\x3c\x3e\x40\x5b-\x5d\x7f-\xff]+|\x5b([^\x0d\x5b-\x5d\x80-\xff]|\x5c[\x00-\x7f])*\x5d))*$/.test( email );
}


$(document).on( 'click', '#validate', function(){
  
  var email = $('#email').val();

  if (validateEmail(email)) 
    console.log('This is a valid email!');
  else 
    console.log('This is NOT a valid email!');
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="email"><input type="button" value="Validate if email" id="validate">
```

Comment: Those email RegExp are most of the time incomplete and/or wrong. And this one does not look correct either. You should avoid to use them and stick with a simple check if the email contains `@`. You need to verify the existence of the email in most cases anyway.

Answer (score 0):

**you can also achieve this by below code** 
[mozilla Ref :](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Form_validation)

```js
var email = document.getElementById("mail");

 //email.setCustomValidity("I expect an e-mail, darling!");
 email.addEventListener("input", function (event) {
 checkEmail(email)
});

function checkEmail(email){


  if (email.validity.patternMismatch) {
    email.setCustomValidity("I expect an e-mail");
      console.log("Invalid")
  }  else {
    email.setCustomValidity("");
    console.log("valid")
  }
  
  }
```

```html
<h3>Show an e-mail field (allows only one email address):</h3>
<form action="/action_page.php">
  E-mail: <input id='mail' type="email" name="emailaddress"pattern="^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$"
  required>
  <input type="submit" onclick="checkEmail(email)" >
</form>
```